# Ошибка при работе в Webpack

Tags: webpack, npm

Подскажите в чем может быть проблема?
Пытаюсь освоить Webpack и при команде npm start получаю ошибку несмотря на то, что npm run build работает адекватно.
В чем проблема?

package.json

```
{
  "name": "webpack-tutorial",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --mode development --open"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack": "^5.4.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.2.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.0"
  }
}
```

Ошибка следующая

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'start'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.14.6
3 info using node@v12.18.4
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info lifecycle webpack-tutorial@1.0.0~prestart: webpack-tutorial@1.0.0
6 info lifecycle webpack-tutorial@1.0.0~start: webpack-tutorial@1.0.0
7 verbose lifecycle webpack-tutorial@1.0.0~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle webpack-tutorial@1.0.0~start: PATH: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Верстка\webpack-tutorial\node_modules\.bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\bin
9 verbose lifecycle webpack-tutorial@1.0.0~start: CWD: C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Верстка\webpack-tutorial
10 silly lifecycle webpack-tutorial@1.0.0~start: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'webpack-dev-server --mode development --open' ]
11 silly lifecycle webpack-tutorial@1.0.0~start: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle webpack-tutorial@1.0.0~start: Failed to exec start script
13 verbose stack Error: webpack-tutorial@1.0.0 start: `webpack-dev-server --mode development --open`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:315:20)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:286:5)
14 verbose pkgid webpack-tutorial@1.0.0
15 verbose cwd C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Верстка\webpack-tutorial
16 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.18363
17 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
18 verbose node v12.18.4
19 verbose npm  v6.14.6
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error webpack-tutorial@1.0.0 start: `webpack-dev-server --mode development --open`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the webpack-tutorial@1.0.0 start script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
  entry: './src/index.js',

  devServer: {
    contentBase: path.join(__dirname, './src'),
    port: 9000
  },

  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  }

};
```

Comment: Добавь файл webpack.config.js   и переименуй папку на рабочем столе `Верстка`   пиши название латиницей

Comment: Папку переименовал и  webpack.config.js создан и настроен базово как сказано на сайте webpack. Но результата 0

Comment: webpack.config.js сюда добавь....

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29916581/webpack-error-while-running-npm-start

Comment: Бесполезно. Там другая ошибка

Answer (score 0):

Первое что стоит попробовать переустановить `npm`:
Находимся в папке с проектом и в терминале пишем

```
npm clean cache
npm install
```

Обычно все ошибки решаются.

Если не помогло, то можно попробовать запустить `webpack-dev-server` без флагов:

```
 "start": "webpack-dev-server"
```